# Finding pst extension file in homedrive using vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I'm having problem with finding pst file in a homedrive. First I try finding in local disk 
and it works like a charm by using these query

```
  Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'pst'
```

Now I'm trying to find a pst file in a homedrive but weren't able to extract the files using these code:

```
  Select * from win32_mappedlogicaldisk
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem and thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. The [Win32_MappedLogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394194(v=vs.85).aspx) class represents _network storage devices_. Nothing to do with _files_. 2. What dou you mean by **homedrive**? If a network share mapped as logical disk - [something like described here](http://it.ubc.ca/services/web-servers-storage/home-drive-storage-service/mapping-or-mounting-your-home-drive-0), then use _Files Collection_ rather than WMI. Something like `Set fso = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject")` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I typically use the path of least resistance.

This batch should work for both...

Usage is: SomeNameHere.bat pst

You could just replace the %1 from the For loop and remove the first IF statement. Then add some commands for handling the PST files when you find them.

```
    @echo off
    :: Using call :label - within a loop will let called label run until end
    :: of batch file.
    :: When the end of file is reached, it goes to the next line in loop.
    if "%1" equ "" goto showusage
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a /o *.%1') do (
    set file=%%a
    call :function0
    )
    endlocal
    goto eof

    :function0
    if "%file%" neq "" goto function1
    if "%file%" equ "" goto function2
    goto function0 

    :function1
    set %file%=%file:&:^&%
    echo.Found %file%
    ::some commands here
    goto eof

    :function2
    echo. 
    goto eof

    :showusage
    cls
    Echo.You did not supply a file extension to search for.
    Echo.
    Echo.Please run the command like this example
    Echo.
    echo.   %~nx0 txt
    Echo.

    :eof
```